# Sanity Check - RxJs Subjects in a Service

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am working in a service with several subjects that I'd like to use to store the application state in.

I would also like to update values stored in subjects when one of the subjects emits.

My current solution to this is to deal with it in kind of getter/setter functions:

```
export class SavedSearchService {
    private cards$ = new BehaviorSubject<Card[] | undefined>(undefined)
    private selectedList$ = new BehaviorSubject<List| undefined>(undefined)
    private extraCardProperties$ = new BehaviorSubject<ExtraProps[]>([])

  setList(list: List): Observable<void> {
    this.selectedList$.next(list)
    return this.updateCards(list)
  }
  
  updateCards(list:List): Observable<void>{
    this.cards$.next(undefined)
    return this.getDataFromBackend(list).pipe(tap(newCards=> this.cards$.next(newCards)))
   }


   getCards():Observable<Card[]>{
    return this.cards$.pipe(combineLatestWith(this.extraCardProperties$.pipe(first()))).pipe(map(cards, extraProps)=>{
     return this.updateCardsWithExtraProps(cards, extraProps)
     })
   }

   updateCardsWithExtraProps(cards: Card[], extraProps: [...]): Card[]{ ... }

...
}
```

This seems to work but... Is this good practice? Any other way to do it? Is it ok to have subscriptions in services? Feels like I should avoid that.

Thank you for your time if you had a look at it. :)

Comment: Strongly recommend NGRX :)

Comment: I would say if your app is small and you have no great concerns about STATE MANAGEMENT the aproach you took or similars will sufice IMHO. If you want more control over the STATE of you app, then may be time to learn a STATE MANAGEMENT library. Bare in mind that although you will have more control the complexity will increase drasticaly as well. That's the tradeof will have to make.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I tend to see "services" as instances of classes that have 2 families of APIs.

One is the set of "command" functions which represent the set of commands they can receive, e.g. query the back end to get the details of the user.

The other is the set of Observables exposed as public properties (since Observables are wrappers around functions, in my opinion a public Observable is an API).

Typically "command" functions do stuff and, when completed with a result, `next` a `Subject` that is the Observable exposed as API.

So, the more natural interaction with such a service is the following:

1. A client registers to the Observables it wants to observe
2. Any client (i.e. either the one which subscribed to the Observable or any other component that shares the same service, e.g. via dependency injection) calls a "command" function do do something.
3. The service does the stuff and then next the `Subject` that is exposed as public Observable
4. As a result of the subscription, the client which subscribed to the public Observable gets updated.

This concept is described in mode details [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/reactive-programming-with-react-and-rxjs-88d2789e408a) and [here](https://www.infoq.com/articles/exploring-architecture-building-game/?itm_source=infoq&itm_campaign=user_page&itm_medium=link).